# erl -make using header file

Tags: compilation, erlang

I want to know how to compile erlang file using `erl -make` depending on hrl header files. This is convenient to compile a batch of files.

I already have known how to compile one file using `erlc -I some_directory some_file.erl`.

Also ,I know how to compile one file under the shell by `c(some_file, [{i, "../include"}]).`